# Warnings with distr package; "Grid for approxfun too wide"

Tags: r, statistics, package

I've tried to use the dist package to create a random variable where the start and stop points have a degree of uncertainty (measured to within a second), but I can't get around the following warning:

> 1: In .discretizeP(e1, lower, upper, h) :
>     Grid for approxfun too wide, increase DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponent

Sometimes the error has first parameter of e2 instead of e1.

Here is an MWE to show my issues:

```
require ( distr )
require ( distrEx )

distroptions("DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponent" = 12)
U <- Unif(Min = 0, Max = 1)
t1 <- 2*U + 53 + 2*U
t2 <- 1*U + 39 + 1*U
t3 <- 1*U + 40 + 1*U       # Warning, e1 and e2
t4 <- convpow(U,2) + 39
t5 <- convpow(U,2) + 40
t6 <- 2*U + 39 + 1*U       # Warning, e2 only

distroptions("DefaultNrFFTGridPointsExponent" = 18)
U <- Unif(Min = 0, Max = 1)
t7 <- 1*U + 40 + 1*U       # Warning, e1 and e2
t8 <- 2*U + 39 + 1*U       # Warning, e2 only
```

While the *convpow* seems to work better, it doesn't help if I have different uncertainties at either end as in t8. Changing the *distroptions* also seems to have no effect.

I'm surprised that shifting the distribution (adding 40 instead of 39) has such an effect. Am I doing something wrong? Can I fix this with something like convpow, or by changing a different option? OR do I need to "roll my own" distribution approximation? There doesn't seem to be an issue with the distributions, but knowing the accuracy is very important for this project, even if I increase the allowed error in some way.

I should add that I intend to do more with the result, such as dividing one r.v. by another r.v., which is my I decided to try distr instead of integrate.

*Probably unnecessary background*

I've only been programming off and on in R for a couple of years. I'm trying to use the *distr* package for the following situation; a number of trials are timed where an object moves at a known speed (which may vary from trial to trial) over a fixed distance. Multiple trials are used to improve the estimate of the distance.

The time cannot be measured exactly. For the sake of argument, the timer has 1s accuracy. The object does not start at time 0, so the time can vary by up to a second at the start and at the end. Thus if the object passes the start at, say, 10s and then the end at 51s, then it could be anywhere from 40 to 42 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't know why `U+40+U` is so much worse than `U+39+U`, I have worked out how to fix my issue.

The convolution works much better as seen with `t4` and `t5` vs. `t2` and `t3`. The problem was then that I couldn't convolve two different uniform distributions, as `convpow` only works with a single distribution type.

The key is that the `+` operator is overloaded in `distr` to take advantage of this. So re-arranging the terms (and dropping the useless coefficients, though I think this may be superfluous) produces a different result:

```
U + 40 + U      # Generates warnings
U + U + 40      # No warnings
```

While it doesn't explain the odd behavior, at least it resolves the issue.